# What is the correct pronunciation of "Ra's Al Ghul"?

Tags: dc, batman, arrowverse, arrow

Across the four screen/game adaptations I'm familiar with, I've heard the name "Ra's" pronounced as "Raz", "Rah-z" and "Ray-sh" - often times, differing even within the same work.

Is there an official or intended (by creators, editors) pronunciation of the name?

**WARNING: massive *Arrow* spoilers for the most recent episode in the [this linked video](http://youtu.be/sr2NTkZS4sA?t=45s)**. (Even the title of the video contains a spoiler).

Comment: What I found so far - the arabic pronunciation is "Raw-Uss". 
The hebrew pronunciation is "Raysh" and then "al gool"

Comment: The fact that an *Arrow* video is is relevant to a question about Ra's Al Ghul is something of a spoiler, itself.

Comment: @KSmarts Ra's and the League of Assassins have been a major part of the show for a season and a half now.

Comment: Notably, the pronunciation on *Arrow* differs between characters, with Americans generally saying "Rahz" and those associated with the League saying "Raysh."  Not sure how this difference developed onset, but it seems to be an acknowledgement of the differing pronunciations between cultures.

Comment: @Huangism is correct to refer to the Arabic pronounciation here; see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algol#Names - "The name Algol derives from Arabic رأس الغول ra's al-ghūl : head (ra's) of the ogre (al-ghūl)".

Comment: SPOILER ALERT: “Lee-ahm Nee-suhn”.

Comment: I speak arabic. Ra'ss el Ghul literally means the head of the monster, perhaps the ogre but not always, we don't have ogres in our culture. As for the pronunciation:
Ra's = Ra'ass,
EL = elle,
Ghoul = Ghoul. 
In arabic there are plenty of letters that sadly don't have equivalent in English. Such as the GH.

Comment: Maybe one day he’ll be played by Raaaahlph Fiennes.

Comment: This question is in dire need of some IPA. I have little to no idea what half these attempted phonetic writings of the word are even supposed to sound like. Unless my very rudimentary knowledge of Arabic phonology is completely off, the Arabic is roughly [ˌrɑʔ(æ)s æl ˈɣuːl], so if the Arabic pronunciation is meant to be the basic, something like /ˈɹɑʔəs/ would be the logical choice in English. The Hebrew is tougher, since it depends on whether we’re talking the regular Modern Hebrew word for ‘head’ (ראש _raʔš_) or the Common Semitic one that gave the letter _resh_ its name (רֵישׁ _reiš_). →

Comment: → If it’s the former, then [ˈɹɑʔeʃ] would be the expected adaptation in English; if it’s the letter, then probably [ɹeɪʃ] or even [ɹεʃ] would be the expected outcome.

Comment: Your YouTube link is dead

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It has been stated by many that correct Arabic pronunciation would be 'Raas.'

> The correct Arabic pronounciation is Ra-us, though Ras is close enough. [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3ARa%27s_al_Ghul#Pronunciation)

This is this bit from Batman Beyond in which Terry says "Raas" and is subsequently corrected by Talia to say "Raysh." This made it a sore spot for me when new Batman trilogy decided to use "Raas."

There are several unsubstantiated (or cited) claims that the creator used and intended 'Raysh.' Indicating a preference for the Hebrew pronunciation for the word.

> The correct [Arabic] way is closer to 'rahs', the way Denny O'Neil (the writer who created the character) intended it to be said is 'raysh'. The the DCAU went with 'raysh', the Nolan movies went with 'rahs'. [reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/batman/comments/1rbcr2/whats_the_actual_pronunciation_of_ras_and_ras_al/cdlh1jw)

On the embedded video there is also a dubios comment which states:

> The creator of the character meant for the pronunciation to be the Hebrew pronunciation Raysh, probably because of the whole Lazarus [pit].

Then there is this [quote](http://www.hitfix.com/the-fien-print/ras-al-ghul-is-coming-to-arrow-and-marc-guggenheim-offers-details) from Executive Producer Marc Guggenheim from Arrow.

> One key issue I wanted to bring up, because it came up last season when I wrote about that third episode, is the pronunciation of Ra's al Ghul's first name, which has traditionally been something close to "Ras" or "Ross" when referred to colloquially, but becomes something closer to "Resh" or "Reesh" when savvy fans discuss him.
>
> "The beauty part of what you guys do is you just have to type it and it's the same spelling even if it's a different pronunciation," Guggenheim laughed. "Basically what we decided to do, and I think you sort saw this in Episode 2.13 when Nissa came to town, is we basically honored the two different pronunciations, some of our characters saying 'Ras' and the ones sorta more in-the-know say 'Resh' and that struck us as a very reasonable compromise. There are clearly two different schools of thought and we wanted both to be represented."

So he seems to think 'Resh' (or 'Raysh') is the more correct pronunciation for the name.

**Update**

At a recent San Diego Comic Con [panel](http://www.comicbookresources.com/article/sdcc-arrow-cast-on-the-five-month-gap-new-identities-malcolm-merlyn) there was some discussion about "Raz" versus "Rayche" from David Ramsey and Stephen Amell.

> He explained why some characters pronounce "Ra's" "Raz" while others say "Rayche." "If you are part of the League of Assassins, you say 'Rayche.' It's a sign of respect and the proper way to pronounce it. If you are outside the League and you're rogue, as a sign of disrespect, you say 'Raz.'" That understanding came about because the actual pronunciation was not clarified on the set until episodes with the "Raz" pronunciation had aired, so, "we had to create a mythology."

**Final Verdict**

At least for Arrow, "Raysh" (or "Rayche") is the correct pronunciation, while "Raas" (or "Raz") is a more derogatory version. In the DCAU, "Raysh" is also the correct version.

For the cinematic Dark Knight trilogy, the correct pronunciation is "Raas."

Answer (score 0):

I know this question already has an accepted answer, but the *incorrect* pronunciation in the Batman movie has always bugged me.

It's the equivalent of calling Bruce Wayne, Broose Wine...

But like with so many other questions in life, the answer is found in [Batman: The Animated Series](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0103359/) :

> *Raysh*

Possibly the first time his name is said aloud outside a DC building.

Answer (score -4):

Every person has their own way of saying the name. Like Stan Lee stated of Thor's mystical hammer, there is technically no wrong way to say it.

Comment: Nope... that's not how names work. My name is my name, if your pronounce it wrong, you're not saying my name.